# Nginx an application redirects on root site

Tags: nginx

Navigate to localhost/app1 redirects me on localhost/login, expected - localhost/app1/login.
Is it possible to change the application redirect to the right place using nginx?

```
location /app1/ {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Used Referer URL to make the right way redirection. The configs below:

nginx.conf - get application name from $http_referer

```
http {
  map $http_referer $app {
    ~*//[a-z0-9_.-]+/([a-z0-9_.-]+)   $1;
  }...
}
```

root.conf - redirect wrong URLs to $app$uri

```
location / {
  if ($http_referer != "") {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /$app$uri redirect;
  }
```

app1.conf - important! The Referer header must be added!

```
location /app1/ {
   proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
   proxy_set_header Referer $http_referer;
   ...
}
```